# Scikit-learn has very low accuracy on LOGISTIC REGRESSION, Random Forest, SVM but has high accuracy on linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This is my dataset

[image: data]

I transformed the columns with string type to float by doing this

```
df2['Sex'] = df['Sex'].astype('category')
df2['Housing'] = df['Housing'].astype('category')
df2['Saving accounts'] = df['Saving accounts'].astype('category')
df2['Checking account'] = df['Checking account'].astype('category')
df2['Purpose'] = df['Purpose'].astype('category')
```

[image]

To train the model:

```
train, test = train_test_split(df2, test_size=0.2)
Y_train = pd.DataFrame()
Y_test = pd.DataFrame()
Y_train["score"] = train["score"]
Y_test["score"] = test["score"]
X_train = train.drop('score', 1)
X_test = test.drop('score', 1)


lr = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=0.9, solver='liblinear', n_jobs=-1)
lr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
```

My accuracy with  LOGISTIC REGRESSION, RandomForest or SVM is very low

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(Y_test,Y_pred)
```

> 0.05

Comment: Accuracy is meaningful only for *classification* problems, while here you want to predict a numeric output; hence, you are in a *regression* setting, where accuracy is meaningless. That said, I wonder how you get a high accuracy with linear regression, as you say (but you don't show).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is **regression**, but you tried **classification** models (Logistic regression, SVM and RandomForest). You should try RandomForestRegressor, SVR (as opposed to SVC) etc.